# Awk command to insert corresponding line numbers except for blank lines

Tags: awk

I'm doing an assignment at the moment and the question that's stumped me is:

> "Write an awk command to insert the corresponding line number before
>   each line in the text file above. The blank line should NOT be
>   numbered in this case."

I have an answer, but I'm struggling to find the explanation of what each component does.

The command is:

```
awk '{print (NF? ++a " " :"") $0}' <textfile.txt>
```

I know that `NF` is the field number, and that `$0` refers to the whole input record. I tried playing around with the command to find what does what, but it always seems to have syntax errors whenever I omit something.

So, my question is what does each component do? What does the `++a` do? The `?` after `NF`? and what does the bit with the quotations do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the blank line be counted, but not numbered?

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `... ? ... : ...` it's an `if-else`. So, it's the same as:

```
if ( NF > 0 ) {
    ++a;
    print a " " $0;
} else {
    print $0;
}
```

`a` is a variable that is only incremented when found a line with fields.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

```
print (NF? ++a " " :"") $0
```

a ternary operator has been used in your solution.
for a blank line NF will be 0 always
so

```
cond?true case:false case
```

if NF is >0 then print a or else print ""
a++ says that after printing increment a by 1 which will be used for next non blank line processing.

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=1}{if($0~/^$/){print}else{print count,$0;count++}}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp.cc
int main ()
{

}
> awk 'BEGIN{count=1}{if($0~/^$/){print}else{print count,$0;count++}}' temp.cc
1 int main ()
2 {

3 }
>
```

Comment: Your description, which has `a++`, does not match the code, which has `++a`, and is incorrect. The variable `a` is incremented *before* it's printed.

Comment: awk treats uninitialized variables as 0 when used in a numeric context, so you don't need the begin clause. Don't be afraid of whitespace, even in a one-liner: readability is important. Written in a more awk-like style: `awk '/^[[:space:]]*$/ {print; next} {print ++count, $0}' file`